# ASP.NET MVC AllowAnonymous Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ASP.NET MVC Project in IIS Anonymous Authentication is Disabled, ASP.NET Impersonation is Enabled and Windows Authentication is Enabled.

In my web.config I have this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true">
```

This part is working, when I goto the web application I get prompted for a username and password, so far so good.

What I am trying to do is allow Anonymous users to be able to goto HomeController Index Method (Home/Index)

I have tried [AllowAnonymous] on the Index method like so

```
[AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult Index () {
      return View();
   }
```

and I have also tried

```
<location path="HomeController/Index">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

and I still get prompted for a username and password, what am I doing wrong? How do I allow Anonymous users to goto Home/Index?

I have also tried:

```
<location path="Home/Index">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

And that did not work.

Comment: In my experience, AllowAnonymous simply doesn't work with integrated windows authentication. IIS is forcing the authentication to happen before it even reaches your MVC code that would say that anonymous access it allowed.

Comment: So would have to allow Anonymous in IIS to get this to work?

Comment: Yes, at which point integrated windows authentication doesn't work. Off the top of my head, a few options are to host the anonymous portion of your site as a different website (perhaps as a virtual application), or to switch to using forms authentication and to manually take the submitted username/password and validate them against AD yourself. The latter means you lose the passwordless authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong path configured in the config file. The convention is to use the Controller name without the post-fix of Controller. So it should be like:

```
<location path="Home/Index">
```

Answer (score 0):

On my project using the ASP.NET MVC 5.x framework, the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute seem to work on all my controllers (decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute) **apart** from the `HomeController`.

I ended up moving my action to another controller and got it to work that way.